# Check javascript confirmation in code behind

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, c#-4.0

I am using the below script to show the confirmation message box. I want top check confirmed status whether its ok or not. How can i check this?

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "temp", "<script language='Javascript'>confirm('ERROR ALERT : " + status + " You can not create record for the above list! Do you want to proceed ?');</script>", false);
```

Answer (score 0):

Confirm returns you boolean `(true or false)` you can assign it to variable, learn more about confirm [here](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_confirm.asp).

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "temp", "<script language='Javascript'>result = confirm('ERROR ALERT : " + status + " You can not create record for the above list! Do you want to proceed ?');</script>", false);
```

Comment: Do you want confirmation status on server side (code behind) ?

Comment: You can store value in hidden field in javascript and access that field on server but confirm is not usually used this way.